# Dynatrace CodeLink AddIn for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I have just downloaded the dynaTrace CodeLink AddIn for Visual Studio.  However, it is not picking up any events or DB calls.  I followed the instuctions on the dynaTrace website.....but I must be missing something.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to address this is posting this question on the dynaTrace Community Forum - http://forums.dynatrace.com